# Creating a dbf that is a subset of another dbf (by criteria)?

Tags: database, ms-access, dbf

I have a dbf I need to import into MS Access, but it is too large to import directly (it's a 4 GB .dbf) although I do not need the whole thing. I only need a subset of the .dbf where the date corresponds to current year (2013), but do not know how to create a new, smaller DBF containing the data so I can import it.

This is something I'd ideally like to automate every day (the 4 GB dbf is dumped every morning and so I'd need to re-acquire the same cut every day).

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Currently-attempted query:

```
select * into destTable IN '\\path\to\backend.mdb'
FROM sourceDBF
WHERE (((sourceDBF.DATE)>"X2*"));
```

(The date part is weird because of the way dates are stored in that particular DBF)

The error (after it spends like 15-20 minutes running the query): http://i49.tinypic.com/b8wb5e.png

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231454/copying-to-from-dbase-data-using-access/11233037#11233037 The idea of using a connection string also works in MS Access queries to create tables in MS Access.

Comment: Will I be able to do that even though the DBF is too large? This dbf is something I cannot import into Access at all whatsoever.

Comment: What database are you using? I thought you mean dBase, but it seems not. (As an aside, the size should not matter if you have a connection string)

Comment: It is a database file that is a .dbf extension. I don't know if this is "dBase" (how to check?). MS Access allows you to import external things like Excel sheets, text files, DBF files, etc. Normally I'd import this dbf but it is too large and Access refuses to import it.

Comment: Did some Googling and I do think it is the same as dBase

Comment: Do not try to import it, link it. MS Access will happily lonk very large tables, although you will need a unique key to work properly with them. There are some notes here that may help http://support.microsoft.com/kb/230125. BTW you may have a FoxPro file.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified/used the correct term -- we do link. I think I remember now: We don't link to the 4 GB file because performing queries that involve that massive thing take forever. However, if we use a maketable query that just cuts the relevant data we need, now we have a still-pretty-big table we need to store somewhere even though the speed is better (and making room for that thing isn't easy). It would be ideal to have a smaller dbf to link to so we don't have to deal with the time/space problems.

Comment: Actually, another thought: Wouldn't I be able to create a separate .mdb backend and use a maketable query to just store the smaller cut and then link to that instead?

I think the problem was that the smaller cut may be > 2 GB... I'll have to experiment/check real quick.

Comment: You can use the linked table to create queries that cut it up into smaller local tables in a separate mdb, if you like. Do not forget to set suitable indexes.

Comment: How do you set indexes/ how do you know what is suitable?

Comment: When you have created the small tables, you can modify them in MS Access to add indexes. A unique index is always good, and an index on fields such as a date that you may use very often in queries to get smaller data sets is often useful. In the end of the day, it is up to you. Index slow down imports and speed up queries.

Comment: What do you mean by "slow down imports" if I am adding an index after I've already got the table at my disposal? Can you link to something that shows how to add the types of indexes you speak of?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177891(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Does not appear to work (the dbf query, that is -- throws error when the dbf is that big). Back to square one.

Comment: What is you query? Edit your post to include the sql.

Comment: It works for me, after a fashion. What errors? What is or is not happening? Did you use the query design window to build the query?

Comment: Yes, I used the query design window. The error doesn't really make much sense -- something like "(unknown) is in use by user ''" -- which is weird because I'm doing this on complete copies of everything where nobody else has access. But I am running it again with different date criteria just in case that's what's causing the problem. I'll post a screenshot if the error arises again here.

Comment: Close everything and restart, just in case there are bits hanging around from previous attempts.

Comment: Did so beforehand, actually -- same error. Posted it in OP.

Comment: How about http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx? You could also try creating the new file on a local directory, say the desktop, rather than on a network path.

Comment: Same error (and nobody else is using the file)

Comment: I am running out of ideas. Can you output to something else altogether, such as a CSV?

Comment: I currently use a .bat file that calls upon DBViewer to convert the DBF to .txt using some filter criteria and then link to that, but the problem is that sometimes a field might have a bad character and so it'll think it's a delimiter instead of a character in the field -- and this screws everything up that uses that data source. You also can't edit a linked text file, either. That's why I am trying to find another method to get this cut of data. I tried to look for a good way to convert DBF to TXT but was unsuccessful. Not sure how CSV conversion would work here.

Answer (score 1):

I know that .DBF files are typically associated with dBASE, FoxPro, Visual FoxPro, and older Clipper applications.  They were all 32-bit and would not allow a single file to exceed the 2 gig file limit.

That said, there is a product from Sybase called Advantage Database Server.  Aside from being it's own SQL Database, it was also engineered to be backward compatible to support the Visual Foxpro community.   With its tools, you can basically hook up directly to a path that has the stand-alone .dbf files (or even part of a database container .dbc) and open the files view them, run queries against them, etc and it would allow capability of going BEYOND the 2 gig file limit.

I would strongly suspect this might be the case.  If so, you might be able to download their tools much like that of others like MySQL or SQL server management tools where you can attach to databases, do table management, run queries, etc.

If that works, you should be able to use it, write a query and select into a new table of just the record set you are looking for (2013 dates).  Then, your Access should be able to query from that smaller table.

I direct search on Google with
sybase advantage server

turns up a lot of stuff.

Hope this helps.